# Open DOORS in batch mode from the command line

Tags: batch-file, command, ibm-doors

I have already tried this and was working till a few days back. Now, there is some Problem.
I can open IBM Rational DOORS in GUI mode by double-clicking on its icon or even using the command line. But, I need to open it in Batch mode so that I don't need to take care of my script and GUI handling.

Has anyone else, too, had the same Problem and fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with DOORS 9.6:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors" -d "port@servername" -user "user" -password "password" -b "pathToFile.dxl"`